# Timeout to logout with reset loop

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to implement an automatic timeout inside of an existing PHP application.

My goal is to have the system notify the user 15 seconds before the automatic timeout is set to occur and give them the opportunity to 'reset' the timeout timer.

I'm using jQueryUI bits as a part of all of this.

[This chart may help describe what I'm trying to do.](http://reljac.com/so_1/timeout.png)

I have a working timer and notification in place.  What I'm looking for is the loop of 
Get prompted for auto logout -> cancel auto logout -> restart timer -> Get prompted for auto logout.  (It's what's in red on my chart.)

Are there any good, existing options for me to do this?

Here's what I have so far, but I think I'm stuck...

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#timeOutNoticeMsg').css('color', '#000000');
    $("#timeOutDialog").dialog({ 
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: { 
            "Cancel Logout": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
            }
        },
    });
},  103000);

var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'logout.php?w=1';
}, 115000);
```

Comment: Won't this log the user out even if they are active on the page?

Comment: Yes it will, unless they click the 'Cancel Logout' button in the diaplg that pops up...doing that clears out the location.href bit...

I'm not as interested in activity on a single page as much as I am interested on going from page to page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include a boolean variable in the "Cancel Logout" function:

```
       "Cancel Logout": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
            logMeOut = false;
        }
```

and then make the logout function dependent on that variable:

```
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function(logMeOut) {
if( logMeOut == true )
{    
    window.location.href = 'logout.php?w=1';
}, 115000);
```

Please note that I'm not a jQuery expert, and I **DO NOT** vouch for the pseudocode above. Figure out the syntax yourself.